# How do you create a keyword search that does not return partial search results in C#

Tags: c#

I am coming across an issue where I created a keyword search bar that also results in partial word search results.  An example would be if someone types in the keyword 'Art Teacher' not only do results for 'Art Teacher' populate but any results with 'art' in them, e.g.'Part-Time Teacher' or 'Charter Teacher'.  I just want the search results for 'Art Teacher' to populate however.

```
 //filter by keywords
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.keywords))
        {
            param.keywords = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(param.keywords.Trim());
            string pattern = @"\S+";
            Regex re = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(param.keywords));
            string[] words = new string[matches.Count];
            if (matches.Count == 1)
            {
                filteredList = FilterKeywords(filteredList, UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(param.keywords));
            }
            else
            {
                if (param.searchType.ToLower() == "all" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.searchType))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    {
                        words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                        filteredList = FilterKeywords(filteredList, UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(words[i]));
                    }

                    //var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<JobResultModel>();
                    //for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    //{
                    //    words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                    //    searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.positionTitle).Contains(words[i]));
                    //}
                    //for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    //{
                    //    words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                    //    searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.city).Contains(words[i]));
                    //}
                    //for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    //{
                    //    words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                    //    searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.districtName).Contains(words[i]));
                    //}
                    //for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    //{
                    //    words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                    //    searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.countyName).Contains(words[i]));
                    //}
                    //for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    //{
                    //    words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                    //    searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.fullCountyName).Contains(words[i]));
                    //}
                    //filteredList = filteredList
                    //    .Where(searchPredicate);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    {
                        words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                        filteredList = FilterKeywords(filteredList, UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(words[i]));
                    }

                    var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<JobResultModel>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    {
                        words[i] = UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(matches[i].Value);
                        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.positionTitle).Contains(words[i]));
                        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.city).Contains(words[i]));
                        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.districtName).Contains(words[i]));
                        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.countyName).Contains(words[i]));
                        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.fullCountyName).Contains(words[i]));
                        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(c => UtilityHelper.CleanKeywords(c.jobType).Contains(words[i]));
                    }
                    filteredList = filteredList
                        .Where(searchPredicate);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [mcve] please.  thanks.

Comment: The regex is splitting the search query in to groups of non-whitespace characters, and searching for each of them.  The quickest solution would be to just change the regex pattern to `.*`, which will match the entire query as if it were single word.  It's not the most elegant, or efficient  way, and leaves a lot of useless code, but it may be the easiest to implement with your current code base.